# How to press enter using UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I have one function setfieldvalue that enters data into a text field. Then I call pressenter function to press enter. Cursor was already in the text field. I am not sure why UFT does not press enter.

```
Public Function PressEnter()
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Wait(1)
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End Function
```

How can I write a function which will press enter where the cursor is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`DeviceReplay`](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2010/09/23/3-ways-to-use-keyboard-input-in-quicktest-professional-type-sendkeys-and-device-replay/).

```
Set devRep = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
devRep.PressKey 28
```

Comment: I tested this with one instance. It worked. If any issues later, I will let you know. Thanks.